# Spring Boot - Camel how to handle multiple processes

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel, multiple-processes

I have 3 Spring Boot - Camel applications which is run individually. I need to chain these processes, say on completion of process A it should initiate process B and then once process B is completed it should proceed with process C. If any of the processes fails in between, the process chain should retry the failed one and continue with the execution to the next one. Also, within process A if there is any failure on any of the steps in the route, then also I need to retry and start from the intermediate step. Can any one help me with the implementation of this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like the [**Pipes and Filters pattern**](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/pipes-and-filters.adoc).

Your 3 applications would be "filters" in this pattern, if you add a **message broker** like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) to the game, you get the "pipes" (message queues) in between and a very nice decoupling.

That would mean that your applications consume from a queue to process new messages and produce into another queue to hand the messages over to the next processing step. For the retries you could use **Camel error handling** (retry of the failed route step) or the **broker redelivery** mechanism with local JMS transactions (retry of the whole route).